# Python, looping through a dataframe using a function with 3 parameters to compare values with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe called "**df_employee**" with the following columns: [company, first_name, last_name,  gender, age ]

I also have another dataframe called "**df_personal** with the following columns: [gender, age, new], where "new" contains the names of different companies and will have like values with the company column in df_employee

I am calling a function called employee_matcher, which takes three parameters, employee_matcher(company, age, gender) and compares values from df_personal to those in df_employee to see if any matches exist. I am able to extract a single row, but am unable to extract all rows that satisify the conditions in df_employee in df_personal and would like to know how to do so. Here is my current code, which outputs

```
    company first_name  last_name   gender  age
286   xyz    James         Kay       Male   21
```

```
def employee_matcher(company, age, gender):
        data = df_employee.loc[(df_employee.company == company) & (df_employee.gender == gender) & (df_employee.age == age)]
        return data

x = employee_matcher(df_personal['new'], df_personal['age'], df_personal['gender'])
x
```

Comment: Have you looked into pandas merging? `pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['company', 'age', 'gender'],how='inner')`

Comment: add some sample of data from both Frames and a sample or frame you want to get